# How can I set the correct position of the text in CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following css code:

```
#content{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 21px;
  text-align: right;
}

#content h1{
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  text-align: right;
}
```

and html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>            
    <body>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>content</h1>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssPDD/1429/). I cannot make the text to be displayed on the right side, it's only on the left side... How can I fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set container's (`#content`) `width` css property to `100%`.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ssPDD/1431/)